# Convert pixels to mm on image

Tags: javascript, image, math, scale, pixel

I am working on a project where I calculate the length of a line drawn by the user on an image. A canvas is set to the image height and width. In order to measure the length of line, I need to convert the pixels into a real life measurement such as millimeters. Each image provides a scaling system such as 1:100...1:25 that the user inputs. My goal is to measure the length of the line in pixels and convert it to real life millimeters depending on the line drawn by the user. I came up with this formula which works but only if the image height and width are 1536 x 912 but doesn't work for other images, refer to the code below.

```
/ Calculate the length of the line using the formula in pixels
  const length = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(endX - startX, 2) + Math.pow(endY - startY, 2));

  // Convert the length from pixels to the scale specified (1:50 in this case) in mm
  //0.02514 is the known measurement within the drawings
  // 176 px (length of line drawn) = 7000 mm (as shown on image) 
  // therefore, 1 px = 0.02514 making the scale work in a 1:50
  const lengthInScalemm = length / 0.02514285714;
```

Comment: I don't think there's any good way to do this on the browser. To this out, you'd need to figure out measurements like PPI (pixels per inch).

Comment: There is no reason or explanation why the relationship between px and mm sizes is different for different sized canvases. Also, mm is a valid unit for css sizes (with the browser taking care of the conversion) so to draw a 1:50 scale canvas representing say, 1 metre, you would simply set the value to the real size/scale (i.e. 1000/50=20mm in this case)

Comment: @DavePritlove CSS `mm` is not in "real-life" mm  it's simply `37.8px` no matter if you're on a mobile device, a desktop computer or even a video projector.

Comment: Why do you need the "real life measurement" exactly? Could you shed more light on your actual project/needs? Maybe there are ways around that you didn't consider.

Comment: @Kaiido I'm not sure what you mean but every device knows exactly how many screen pixels there are in a 'real' mm. I regularly use mm css units to render drawing that are scaled perfectly to the real dimensions when saved or printed. I think it's an irrelevant point anyway as the OP is not trying to render mms but to consistently scale units (which he can do precisely by setting mm/scale as a css dimension *regardless of the device or 'real' screen size*)

Comment: @DavePritlove `1cm = 37.8px` is just how it's defined: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-4/#cm And, no, not all devices can know how many screen pixels there is in a mm. Take for instance video projectors, they don't know how far the projection screen will be and thus don't know what size the image will be rendered at. But even if we stay in the monitors area, not all of them do know/expose that details, and for the few that do, no browser does read the EDID data, so no browser does know the actual "real life" size of the monitor. [1/2]

Comment: See [this thread](https://discourse.wicg.io/t/one-inch-is-not-an-inch/1228) where it was asked that new units be added, but see how it didn't get any traction from both specs editors and implementers, quite on the contrary. [2/2]

Comment: @Kaiido I have nothing to argue with you about as you're arguing semantics that make no relevant point nor change the reality that (as you say yourself by repeating the equivalence) that every device knows exactly what a mm is. Whether the device displays a mm as such is irrelevant. css mm are not named for fun, they are, millimetres. I have made hundreds of perfectly real-scaled images using it.

Comment: No, my point is that `1mm` is not one millimeter. Read the links I provided. And 1px is not one device pixel either. Your code were working only for your 96ppi config.